# QGraphicsPixmapItem is one pixel too large if I set the item selectable

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qpixmap

My `QGraphicsPixmapItem` has to report a correct size - its initial size should match the original image size.

I notice something odd if I make the item selectable: the size reported is one pixel too large.

Is this to be expected ?
Will this behavior be consistent for all `QGraphicsPixmapItems` that are set selectable ?
(And can I therefore override the `boundingRect()` to subtract 1 from the size reported by the `QGraphicsPixmapItem::boundingRect()` each time ?)

Simple check, with any image:

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem p;
p.setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(0, QObject::tr("Open Image File"),
                 QString(), QObject::tr(
                 "Png files (*.png);;Jpeg files (*.jpg *.jpeg);;Bitmap files (*.bmp)"));
QPixmap pixmap(fileName);
qDebug("%d %d", pixmap.size().width(), pixmap.size().height());
p.setPixmap(pixmap);
qDebug("%f %f", p.boundingRect().width(), p.boundingRect().height());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp#L9578), you will see that it adds half a pixel to each direction when the `ItemIsSelectable` flag has been set:

```
if (d->flags & ItemIsSelectable) {
    qreal pw = 1.0;
    return QRectF(d->offset, d->pixmap.size()).adjusted(-pw/2, -pw/2, pw/2, pw/2);
}
```

Comment: thanks... I wonder why that is... must be to allow draw of selection rectangle

Comment: That would be my assumption as well.